# Spark YARN Cluster mode get this error "Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster"

Tags: apache-spark

I have this job running fine in YARN client mode, however in Cluster mode I get the following error.

*Log Contents:
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster
End of LogType:stderr*

I have not set spark.yarn.jars or the spark.yarn.archive. However in the trace, I do see the spark-yarn jar getting uploaded. Is there any additional setting needed here ?

*16/11/01 10:49:49 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/etc/security/keytabs/spark.keytab -> hdfs://beixvz579:8020/user/sifsuser/.sparkStaging/application_1477668405073_0026/spark.keytab
16/11/01 10:49:50 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/sifsuser/spark200/jars/spark-yarn_2.11-2.0.0.jar -> hdfs://beixvz579:8020/user/sifsuser/.sparkStaging/application_1477668405073_0026/spark-yarn_2.11-2.0.0.jar
16/11/01 10:49:50 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/sifsuser/lib/sparkprogs.jar -> hdfs://beixvz579:8020/user/sifsuser/.sparkStaging/application_1477668405073_0026/sparkprogs.jar*

Answer (score 6):

The jar is spark-yarn_2.11-2.4.0.jar(my version) which location is $SPARK_HOME/jars/

first step: (add this into spark-default.conf)

```
 spark.yarn.jars hdfs://hadoop-node1:9000/spark/jars/*
```

second step:

```
 hadoop fs -put $SPARK_HOME/jars/*  hdfs://hadoop-node1:9000/spark/jars/
```

Comment: I config the  `spark.yarn.jars=hdfs:///tmp/spark/*` in cdh and deploy it,  but the local  file `/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf ` spark.yarn.jars not change,  default  value `spark.yarn.jars=local:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/jars/*,local:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/hive/*`   , how to deal with it

Answer (score -3):

After a lot of debugging, I found out this error was thrown due to a missing class that the ApplicationMaster was dependent on. In my case it was one of the logging jars that AM class is dependent on. After adding the additional jars, I can now submit jobs.

Comment: can you elaborate on which jar you needed.  Having the same issue.

Comment: same here  . which jar  ?

Comment: Anyone find out which jar?